# Stop VSC from showing all javascript files as React files

Tags: icons, visual-studio-code

I think it's weird that the default file icon theme shows that all Javascript files are React files now. Can that be changed without having to download a new theme?

I'm not even using React in this project.
[image]

Comment: Please remove the javascript and icons tags. It's not related to any javascript thing. Add **visual-studio-code** tag.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this solves your issue.  In the bottom right side of your **VSC** tool, click on **javascript react** and it opens up a dropdown list, In that please select **Javascript** option. I have attached a screenshot of **VSC code** tool image for your reference. [image]

Comment: My configured language is set to JavaScript and not JavaScript React and I still get the React icons

Comment: Actually I checked on my other computer and I can't even type in JavaScript in the search to change the language mode to JavaScript. Weird.